# spring-boot native-image fails on graalvm compile

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have an existing Spring Boot app that I would like to build as a native image, I am building based on [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-native-image)

**Environment**:

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 21.0.0.2 (build 25.282-b07-jvmci-21.0-b06, mixed mode)

native-image-maven-plugin, 21.0.0.2

spring-aot-maven-plugin, 0.9.1

**Build:**

mvn -Pnative-image package

**Args**:

```
--no-fallback
--report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime
--allow-incomplete-classpath
-H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces
```

**Errors**:

```
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder was unintentionally initialized at build time. To see why javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder

com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:

javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder was unintentionally initialized at build time. To see why javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder
                at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:68)
                at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ConfigurableClassInitialization.checkDelayedInitialization(ConfigurableClassInitialization.java:539)
                at com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationFeature.duringAnalysis(ClassInitializationFeature.java:226)
                at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$8(NativeImageGenerator.java:740)
                at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:70)
                at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:740)
                at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:563)
                at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:476)
                at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
                at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
                at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
                at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
                at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
```

With that, I change args to:

```
--no-fallback
--report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime
--allow-incomplete-classpath
--trace-class-initialization=javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder
--initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
-H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces
```

**Errors**:

```
javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder was unintentionally initialized at build time. org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
                at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.<clinit>(FactoryFinder.java:45)
                at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:127)
                at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:79)
                at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.recordEvents(SaxEventRecorder.java:57)
                at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:151)
                at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
                at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
                at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
                at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
                at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
                at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
```

What do I need to do to correct this error?

Comment: try this --initialize-at-run-time=org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

Comment: @MunishChouhan -  Yes, I have tried this and get:
`Error: Incompatible change of initialization policy for org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder: trying to change BUILD_TIME from the command line to RUN_TIME from the command line
Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
`

Comment: Anyone else can provide some help here would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: share command line options you are using to build it

Comment: @MunishChouhan, for building I am using `mvn clean package -Pnative-image` where `native-image` is the profile defined in my pom.xml file like the one in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_build_the_native_application_2)

Comment: yes please share the build args in your pom file

Comment: @MunishChouhan - Here are the args:
`--verbose
--no-fallback
--enable-https
--report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime
--allow-incomplete-classpath
--initialize-at-run-time=org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
--trace-class-initialization=javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder
-H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces`

Comment: @emoritz have you found a solution? I am fighting with this StaticLoggerBinder issue for the second day now, having arrived to the same initialize-at-run-time /  Incompatible change of initialization policy loop